# saslpasswd2 support for Berkeley

Tags: arch-linux, database, sasl

I have SASL databases, used by postfix and generated with `saslpasswd2`, on several CentOS 7 machines ( saslpasswd2/LibSasl: 2.1.26 ). They have the Berkeley DB (hash, version 9, native byte-order) format.

Since changing my development system to Arch (recently from Solus), I can no longer test updating such a database (synced from CentOS) with my update scripts that do:

```
$ echo "pass123" | /usr/sbin/saslpasswd2 -p -c -f sasldb2 -u some.domain john.doe@some.domain
saslpasswd2: generic failure
```

The `saslpasswd2` on Arch is version 2.1.27 and on both the CentOS machines and the Arch  machine have `libdb 5.3` installed. Creating a sasldb2 db file from scratch gives a Berkeley format DB on CentOS 7 and a GNU dbm format db on Arch.

I could change the development machine to first convert the db whenever it is rsync-ed, and I could probably also update the CentOS machines if it is documented that support for BerkeleyDB has been dropped by saslpasswd2. But I rather understand why this is happening, and maybe fix Arch to also support Berkeley Db via `saslpasswd2`

What is causing this generic failure, how could I fix this?

(The file is writeable and I compared the hash on both machines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this again and compiled libsasl from scratch (https://github.com/cyrusimap/cyrus-sasl/releases/download/cyrus-sasl-2.1.28/cyrus-sasl-2.1.28.tar.gz). That way de recommended ( according to doc/legacy/install.html in the tar archive) berkeleydb format is supported by `saslpasswd2` (and `sasldblistusers2).